# REST API, Swift, Automatic Update

Tags: ios, swift, rest, model-view-controller

I'm currently struggling to find an easy-to-use programming approach/design pattern, which solves the following problem:

I've got an REST API where the iOS app can request the required data. The data is needed in different ViewControllers. But the problem is, that the data should "always" be up to date. So I need to set up a timer which triggers a request every 5-20 seconds, or sth like that. Everytime the data changes, the view needs to be updated (at the current viewcontroller, which is displayed).
I tried some stuff with delegation and MVC Pattern, but it's kind a messy. How is it done the right way?

In my current implementation I only can update the whole UICollectionView, not some specific cells, because I don't know how the data changed. My controller keeps track of the data from the api and updates only if the hash has changed (if data changed on the server). My models always holds the last fetched data.
It's not the perfect solution, in my opinion..

I also thought about models, that keep themselves up to date, to abstract or virtualise my Rest-API. In this case, my controller doesn't even know, that it isn't directly accessible data.

Maybe someone can help me out with some kind of programming model, designpattern or anything else. I'm happy about anything!

---

UPDATE: current implementation

The Controller, which handles all the data

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
import SwiftyTimer

class OverviewController {

  static let sharedInstance = OverviewController()

  let interval = 5.seconds
  var delegate : OverviewControllerUpdateable?
  var model : OverviewModel?
  var timer : NSTimer!

  func startFetching() -> Void {
    self.fetchData()

    timer = NSTimer.new(every: interval) {
      self.fetchData()
    }

    timer.start(modes: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
  }

  func stopFetching() -> Void {
    timer.invalidate()
  }

  func getConnections() -> [Connection]? {
    return model?.getConnections()
  }

  func getConnectionsSlave() -> [Connection]? {
    return model?.getConnectionsSlave()
  }

  func getUser() -> User? {
    return model?.getUser()
  }

  func countConnections() -> Int {
    if let count = model?.getConnections().count {
      return count
    }
    return 0
  }

  func countConnectionsSlave() -> Int {
    if let count = model?.getConnectionsSlave().count {
      return count
    }
    return 0
  }

  func fetchData() {
    ApiCaller.doCall(OverviewRoute(), completionHandler: { (data, hash) in

      if let actModel = self.model {
        if (actModel.getHash() == hash) {
          //no update required
          return
        }
      }

      var connections : [Connection] = []
      var connectionsSlave : [Connection] = []

      for (_,connection):(String, JSON) in data["connections"] {
        let connectionObj = Connection(json: connection)
        if (connectionObj.isMaster == true) {
          connections.append(connectionObj)
        } else {
          connectionsSlave.append(connectionObj)
        }
      }

      let user = User(json: data["user"])

      //model needs update
      let model = OverviewModel()
      model.setUser(user)
      model.setConnections(connections)
      model.setConnectionsSlave(connectionsSlave)
      model.setHash(hash)

      self.model = model

      //prevent unexpectedly found nil exception
      if (self.delegate != nil) {
        self.delegate!.reloadView()
      }

      }, errorHandler: { (errors) in
      }) { (progress) in
    }
  }
}

protocol OverviewControllerUpdateable {
  func reloadView()
}
```

The model, which holds the data:

```
class OverviewModel {

  var user : User!
  var connections : [Connection]!
  var connectionsSlave : [Connection]!
  var connectionRequests : [ConnectionRequest]!
  var hash : String!

...
}
```

And in the ViewController, I use it like this:

```
class OverviewVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, OverviewControllerUpdateable {

    let controller = OverviewController.sharedInstance

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.controller.delegate = self
        self.controller.startFetching()
    }

    //INSIDE THE UICOLLECTIONVIEW DELEGATE METHODS
    ...
    if let user : User = controller.getUser() {
      cell.intervalTime = interval
      cell.nameLabel.text = "Ihr Profil"
    }
    ...

    func reloadView() {
        self.userCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the problem is at this moment? Maybe show some code?

Comment: updated the post!

Comment: Push notification is better than polling, but if you can't do that then a singleton with a timer is another approach.  Have a look at IGListKit for updating the collection view - https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit

Comment: I see your point, you are totally right. But in my case, push is no option. Does it make sense to save my data directly into coredata from my api and my view only reads data out of coredata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Singleton` object to fetch your data periodically, then post notifications (using `NSNotificationCenter`) when the data is updated. Each view controller dependent on the data would listen for these notifications, then reload UI based on the updated data.

Comment: I think NSNotificationCenter did it for me. Delegation works just with one VC, with the Observer-Pattern I could use more than one VC. I actually implemented it now and it works fine. No mess with setting the delegation over and over again. I also changed my controller and save the data persistent and load it, if no data was fetched yet. I also implemented the algorithm which is used in IGListKist to calculate the changes for the UICollectionView.

Comment: That's good news. The observer pattern makes a lot of sense for this use case. In the future, you could consider making your own Listener protocol on your data fetcher much like you would with a delegate, but be able to register multiple listeners at once. This is a bit cleaner than `NSNotificationCenter` because it enforces listeners to conform to a protocol. The target/action pattern used by notification center is not very "Swifty"

Comment: You are totally right. I will read about it and refactor my code. Thanks, mate!